# HTTP Status 500 - org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware

Tags: java, spring

> HTTP Status 500 - org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message org/springframework/beans/factory/Aware
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

### How to resolve this error? Please help!!

Comment: The server logs will have a more detailed message. Can you share that?

Comment: Please tell how to get the server logs file

Comment: what kind of webserver/applicationserver you use (jboss, tomcat,..)? On which OS?

Answer (score 0):

You either do not have the spring-beans jar on the classpath or you have different versions. Make sure that you are building with the same version. Also make sure that all the versions of the various Spring jars are the same.

Comment: how to check whether I have spring beans jar on my classpath ?

Comment: Just share the log file of you application server.

Comment: Please check the dependency is added there for spring-beans in that file.

Comment: spring beans version is 3.0.1 spring version is 3.5.1

Comment: try the latest version 4.0.5.RELEASE. Please check whether you have the full listing of spring framework jars in your classpath from this link http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/